# "Unregistered Android application" text is displayed in User profile info permission dialog

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I have integrated Google sign-in in my application. I am able to successfully login every time but when I have added new google account in the device and try to login with that, I see the attached pop up dialog. I don't understand why it says "Unregistered android application". How to register the application in that case?

Attached pop up dialog : [Attached Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WB59.png)

I am using the following code :

```
        try {

            String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail,
                    "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
            return token;

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(userRecoverableException.getIntent(), USER_RECOVERABLE_AUTH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can anyone please guide me how to register the app? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Your app is not having access to log in with newly added account. It is default google behaviour to add account.

Comment: Yes I agree, but why does it show as "Unregistered android application" ? I tried to do the same with another app but it dint show me that text.

Comment: The another app you are trying to login with : is it from play store ?

Comment: Nope not yet in play store. So, does it need to be signed to make it registered application?

Comment: Go to this link and check whether your other is already registered. If yes then delete and try to login again. You will notice the difference. https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Comment: Yes the other application is seen in the link. So what do I need to do to get the app on that list? Thanks

Comment: I was able to find out the solution for this. Fix was I had to create an Oauth client id under corresponding project in google console.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is using your app via an APK, the permission request dialog with show UNREGISTERED ANDROID APPLICATION. Its better to publish your app on play store to avoid this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The another solution what I found was to create Oauth Client Id.