# 'Unregistered Application' shown in Google+ sign in consent screen

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I have made an Android application which is debug key signed (app-debug.apk)

I have also created corresponding Android Client-ID on Google Dev Console with debug keystore key and correct package name.

Still when I try to login into application, the consent screen shows 'UnRegistered Application'.

Comment: I am having a similar problem here  with google calendar api.

Comment: "I was able to find out the solution for this. Fix was I had to create an Oauth client id under corresponding project in google console." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328664/unregistered-android-application-text-is-displayed-in-user-profile-info-permis